# Missing caffeine dependency for Corda Enterprise 4.0

Tags: corda, caffeine

When attempting to compile my project on Corda Enterprise 4.1 for the first time this stack trace for a missing dependency came up.

How can I include the correct Caffeine dependency?

````
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':corda-domain:compileClasspath'.
  > Could not find com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.7.0-r3-fifty.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/C:/Users/syhashmi/.m2/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        file:/C:/Users/syhashmi/.m2/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        https://jitpack.io/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        https://jitpack.io/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
        file:/C:/code-azure/lcacordapp/lib/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.pom
        file:/C:/code-azure/lcacordapp/lib/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0-r3-fifty/caffeine-2.7.0-r3-fifty.jar
    Required by:
        project :corda-domain > com.r3.corda:corda-core:4.1```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda Enterprise 4.0 there is a patched version of Caffeine required to compile.

Documentation on how to add this dependency can be found here: https://docs.corda.r3.com/clientrpc.html#connecting-to-a-node-via-rpc

Comment: I think that patch isn't needed in anymore, but they haven't upgraded to the official 2.7 release.

Comment: Good point @BenManes. The Corda engineering team has made a note to get back to the official public version.